# Retrieve data according to selected value of combobox using php mysql, without redirecting to other page

Tags: php, mysql, combobox

I am developing a project in which i have a website in php and database in mysql. I have linked them well. Now i have combobox in which i have populated it with the data from database. Now the problem is that, on selecting any value from the combobox, the data from database should be displayed below according to value of selected field in combobox without redirecting to any other page.

Answer (score 0):

Without reloading the page?  Or just without navigating to another page?

If reloads are ok, just check if the fields are set, and if so, render the page differently.

I suspect you mean without reloads though.  For that, you'll need to use AJAX.

There's plenty of tutorials and how-tos out there if AJAX is the path you go.  Until you have a specific question, not sure how much help we can give you without going way overboard.

Comment: Thanks for replying Corbin. I meant that page should be same(no navigation to other page).
But is there any other option other than using AJAX, because i haven't used AJAX earlier.

Comment: Do you mean no navigation as in the same page reloading is ok, or as in you do not want any reloading?  If you mean no reloading, then AJAX is your only (reasonable) choice.

Comment: Ok i will refer AJAX tutorials...
Thanks once again.